# Verify the markov property for a sum of processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, poisson-process

I'm given such a problem and I'm seeking for help.
Let {$X_n:n>1$} be an i.i.d. process with Poisson marginal PMF $p_x(k)$ = $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$, $k \geq 0$, and let $N_l = \sum_{k=1}^{l}X_k$ and where $N_0 = 0$. Is $\{N_l\}_{l\geq 0}$ a Markov process? Explain in detail.
I'm wondering what the random process with poisson marginal pmf means, does it mean that X is a poisson process? Then if this is true, then I can try to prove the sum of poisson processes is also poisson, then N is a homogeneous poisson process, next homogeneous poisson process is markov process. I'm not sure whether this is the right way. 
Can someone give me some help on this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following fact:

If $(X_n)_n$ are independent random variables and the stochastic process $(Y_n)_n$ respects an identity of the form $Y_{n+1} = f_n(Y_n,X_{n+1})$, then $(Y_n)_n$ is a markov process.

Proof:

$\mathbb{E}[\phi(Y_{n+1})|Y_1,\ldots,Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[\phi(f_n(Y_n,X_{n+1}))|Y_1,\ldots,Y_n] = \mathbb{E}[\phi(f_n(y,X_{n+1}))]_{y=Y_{n}}$, which is $\sigma(Y_n)$-measurable.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I don't know what $\phi$ and $\sigma$ - measuable means. I think in my course, for this question only the definition of markov process is available: For $t_1 < t_2$, P($X(t_2) \leq x_2|X(t), t \leq t_1$) = P($X(t_2) \leq x_2|X(t_1)$)

Comment: I'm wondering what the random process with poisson marginal pmf means, does it mean that X is a poisson process? Then if this is true, then I can try to prove the sum of poisson processes is also poisson, then N is a homogeneous poisson process, next homogeneous poisson process is markov process. I'm not sure whether this is the right way.

Comment: $\phi$ is a general bounded measurable function, it is $\chi_{\cdot \leq x_2}$ in your case. Moreover, it's easy to see that the Markov property is equivalent to the LHS in your formula to be $\sigma(X_{t_1})$-measurable, i.e. "only depend on $X_{t_1}$".  Anyway, I think it means that the random variables $X_n$ are iid and each of them has a Poisson law, with parameter $\lambda$, as described by the formula you gave. @Bill